# Scanner not picking up contents of the file?

Tags: java, arraylist, java.util.scanner

I have a small problem/bug in my program that won't scan in the contents correctly.
I believe I am using the correct command?
ex: `java homework5 hwk5sample1.txt`
Why don't any contents get scanned and stored in my `ArrayList`?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class homework5 {

  public static int penny = 1;
  public static int nickle = 5;
  public static int dime = 10;
  public static int quarter = 25;
  public static int halfDollar = 50;
  public static int dollar = 100;
  public static int change;

  public static void main(String[] args)
    throws FileNotFoundException {

    ArrayList<Integer> coinTypes = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    File f = new File (args[0]);
    Scanner input = new Scanner(f);
       while (input.hasNextInt()) {
            System.out.println("Found next int"); //used for debugging
            int i = input.nextInt();
            coinTypes.add(i);
            if (input.hasNextLine()) {
               change = input.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Found change"); //used for debugging
                System.out.println("Change: " + change);
            }
       }
    System.out.println(coinTypes); //used for debugging
  }
}
```

**NOTE** the extra `System.out.println()`are used to show me in the output that the scanner has found what is specified, obviously nothing is showing up. What is wrong?

```
output: []
```

here is my `hwk5sample1.txt` file I use in the command

```
// Coins available in the USA, given in cents.  Change for $1.43?
1 5 10 25 50 100
143
```

any and all help is appreciated! Thank you

**EDIT** In my assignment description, it needs to be able to ignore comments like that and still work, as the tester will use similar files

Comment: What happens if you remove the comment from the top of the text file?

Comment: `hasNextInt()` checks to see if the next character(s) in the file / input are an integer. "//" is not an integer, so `hasNextInt()` returns `false`

Comment: Then it works, not as I want it to but that isn't the current issue. The catch is in the project description it must be able to ignore any comments in the file. I'll add that to my question now

Comment: `1)` Grab a whole line `2)` Check if it has an int or not `3)` If no int, move to the next line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add an `input.nextLine()` to read that comment line

#### CODE

```
input.nextLine();
while (input.hasNextInt()) {
    System.out.println("Found next int"); // used for debugging
    int i = input.nextInt();
    coinTypes.add(i);
    if (input.hasNextLine()) {
        change = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Found change"); // used for debugging
        System.out.println("Change: " + change);
    }
}
```

#### OUTPUT

```
Found next int
Found change
Change: 5
Found next int
Found change
Change: 25
Found next int
Found change
Change: 100
Found next int
[1, 10, 50, 143]
```

Comment: Ok that did the trick thanks! I will accept this answer when I can